# Compile error Unresolved reference: DatabaseHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am creating a project (I only have one activity and I already have thousands of problems), I am starting with Kotlin and watching some videos and reading tutorials little by little I have been mounting the project. But I am getting the following compile error.

Compile error Unresolved reference: DatabaseHelper

To be more specific the expanded error is:
e: file:///C:/Users/USER/AndroidStudioProjects/knbktlnbrd/app/src/main/java/com/example/knbktlnbrd/MainActivity.kt:14:31 Unresolved reference: DatabaseHelper

This is the code of the DatabaseHelper.kt file

```
package layout

import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class DatabaseHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "KNBKTLNBRD", null, 1) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        // Crea la tabla KnbProy
        db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE KnbProy (Id_Proyecto INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Nombre TEXT)"
        )

        // Inserta algunos proyectos de ejemplo
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO KnbProy (Nombre) VALUES ('Proyecto 1')")
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO KnbProy (Nombre) VALUES ('Proyecto 2')")
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO KnbProy (Nombre) VALUES ('Proyecto 3')")
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // No se implementa en este ejemplo
    }
}
```

This is the code of the MainActivity.kt file

```
package com.example.knbktlnbrd

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.knbktlnbrd.ui.theme.KnbktlnbrdTheme
import com.example.knbktlnbrd.DatabaseHelper


import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: ProjectAdapter
    private lateinit var dbHelper: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        /*setContent {
            KnbktlnbrdTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = ProjectAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        dbHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)

        loadProjects()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_add_project -> {
                // Abrir la actividad de creación de proyectos
                // Implementa la lógica según tus necesidades
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    private fun loadProjects() {
        val db: SQLiteDatabase = dbHelper.readableDatabase
        val projection = arrayOf("Id_Proyecto", "Nombre") // Columnas que deseas obtener

        val cursor: Cursor = db.query(
            "KnbProy",
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )

        val projects = mutableListOf<Project>()

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val projectId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id_Proyecto"))
            val projectName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Nombre"))

            // Genera un color pastel diferente para cada tarjeta
            val cardColor = generatePastelColor()

            val project = Project(projectId, projectName, cardColor)
            projects.add(project)
        }

        cursor.close()
        db.close()

        adapter.setProjects(projects)
    }

    private fun generatePastelColor(): Int {
        val random = java.util.Random()
        val hue = random.nextInt(360).toFloat()
        val pastelColor = Color.HSVToColor(floatArrayOf(hue, 0.3f, 1f))
        return pastelColor
    }

}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    KnbktlnbrdTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

This is the code of the  build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    //id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10"
}

/*repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()  //jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2"
    }
}*/

android {
    namespace 'com.example.knbktlnbrd'
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.knbktlnbrd"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:1.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.4.3'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.4.3'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.4.3'

}
```

The DatabaseHelper.kt file is located at knbktlnbrd/app/src/main/java/com/example/knbktlnbrd/DatabaseHelper.kt

Still the following error is being generated

e: file:///C:/Users/USER/AndroidStudioProjects/knbktlnbrd/app/src/main/java/com/example/knbktlnbrd/MainActivity.kt:14:31 Unresolved reference: DatabaseHelper

This is the line you are referencing in the MainActivity.kt file
import com.example.knbktlnbrd.DatabaseHelper

Could someone please tell me what generates this error in the code? I greatly appreciate it.

I add screenshot of my Android Studio environment for the project in question. You can see that DatabaseHelper is in the correct directory.

[Screenshot of my Android Studio environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQlq2.png)

Comment: The package statement of your `DatabaseHelper` is apparently `package layout`, but from your description it should probably be `package com.example.knbktlnbrd`